# How can you make Python code run Multiple Times for SUMO?

Tags: python, simulation, sumo

I have a traffic simulation that is running in the simulation tool known as SUMO and I am trying to have the simulation run repeatedly multiple times (about 50 times at the most), but for the sake of this example I will use 10 times. My main code is in another Python file and it requires that arguments be passed into it prior to running. This code is quite lengthy in nature and has multiple Python functions in it so I will not post it in this forum, but for sake of simplification lets call it `performSIM.py`.

My other Python code that is responsible for repeating the main code looks something like this:

```
import traci
from sumolib import checkBinary
import argparse
import performSIM

for i in range(10):
   pythonFile = str(performSIM)
   exec(pythonFile)
```

I was wondering what is the  right way to loop my main code so that runs the simulation 10 times repeatedly? When I run the lines of code above I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\#####\Sumo\USA Road Network SUMO_2021\running_Python.py", line 8, in <module>
    exec(pythonFile)
  
File "<string>", line 1

<module 'performSIM' from 'C:\\Users\\#####\\Sumo\\USA Road Network 
SUMO_2021\\performSIM.py'>
    
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

How exactly can I fix this issue so this error does keep showing up?

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your `performSIM` should have one main function, if it does not have one yet you should restructure it in such a way that it does. A common pattern is to pass the command line arguments to the main function as a parameter. So `performSIM.py` could look like this:

```
import sys

def main(args):
    # parse the args
    # do other useful stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Then your other script can simply do

```
import sys
import performSIM

for i in range(10):
    performSIM.main(sys.argv)
```